# Http post response needs to be saved and retrieved in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, post

I am getting a response from my `this.http.post`. Below is my code

```
this.http.post('http://funiks.com/adminv7/offline-api/login.php', {username: user_form_value,password: password_form_value})
  .subscribe(
    (response)=> console.log(response)
  );
```

and i want to **save the response** by using something like this **in local storage** , this is how i do in js but please guide how can i save in angular and exactly where i need to place the code -

```
 localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUserANG",JSON.stringify(response));
```

Please guide, similarly how do i get the result back in a variable ? **in js i do like this and fetch the username from the data::**

```
loggeduser_array  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getLoggedInUser"));
    console.log(loggeduser_array.username);
```

Please see the response in the console below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to add response to localstorage

```
.subscribe(
   response=>{
   localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUserANG",JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

Comment: This is the result i am getting with my js code - https://pastebin.com/tb1dGA1f , how to use if success and fetch data.user as in js like this - `$.ajax({
    url: 'http://funiks.com/adminv7/offline-api/login.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dict),
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
 if(data.status=="SUCCESS") {
    localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUser",JSON.stringify(data.user));`  but in angular i am getting this - https://pastebin.com/W49NAQvz , HOW TO GET SIMILAR RESULT ??

Comment: use  `JSON.parse(response._body).user`  since the response body is a string and not a object

Comment: But cant i save only the things i am saving using html5 or js , in angular i am saving so much unwanted in local storage, i only want to save similar stuff as being saved using my html5 method, please guide how do i do that

Comment: For angular always use `response._body` which will be similar  `data` in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is not js, It's HTML5 feature

```
   const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  var loginDetail = {username: user_form_value,password: password_form_value};

this.http.post('http://funiks.com/adminv7/offline-api/login.php', JSON.stringify(loginDetail),{headers})
  .subscribe(
    (response)=>
localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUserANG",JSON.stringify(response));
console.log(response);
  );
//  Just get local storage value where you need.
loggeduser_array  = localStorage.getItem("getLoggedInUser");
    console.log(loggeduser_array.data); // you stored promise as response so while get try like this.
```

Comment: This is the result i am getting with my js code - pastebin.com/tb1dGA1f , how to use if success and fetch data.user as in js like this - $.ajax({ url: 'http://funiks.com/adminv7/offline-api/login.php', type: 'POST', contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json', data: JSON.stringify(dict), }) .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { if(data.status=="SUCCESS") { localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUser",JSON.stringify(data.u‌​ser)); but in angular i am getting this - pastebin.com/W49NAQvz , HOW TO GET SIMILAR RESULT ??

Comment: I think your API doesn't return any data

Comment: i attached a screenshot it is returning, i also attached the pastebin link, did you see that ?..attaching again for you---> result with angular - pastebin.com/W49NAQvz , result with js -  pastebin.com/tb1dGA1f